# Request customizada validando campo unique no update

Tags: laravel, api

Bom dia.
Pessoal, tenho uma request criada para validação de usuários, porém, quando vou atualizar um registro ela valida o campo unique que setei na validação.. tentei passar o $this->id junto para que ele ignore, porém, sem sucesso.. alguém já passou por isso?

Laravel versão: 8.0

Obs: estou desenvolvendo tudo para API's.

Código controller

```
public function update(UsuarioRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $usuario = Usuario::find($id);
        if($usuario){
            Usuario::find($id)->update($request->all());
            return response()->json("Usuario atualizado com sucesso", 201);
        }else{
            return response()->json("Usuario nao encontrado", 200);
        }
    }
```

Código Request

```
 public function rules()
    {

        $rules = [
            'nome'              => 'required|max:100|min:2',
            'sobrenome'         => 'required|max:100|min:2',
            'cpf'               => 'required|unique:usuario',
            'rg'                => 'required|unique:usuario',
            'data_nascimento'   => 'required|date',
            'rua'               => 'required|max:300|min:2',
            'bairro'            => 'required|max:300|min:2',
            'cidade_id'         => 'integer',
            'semestre_id'       => 'integer',
            'periodo_letivo_id' => 'integer',
            'email'             => 'required|max:200|email|unique:usuario',
            'status'            => 'required|integer',
            'profissao_id'      => 'integer',
            'sexo_id'           => 'integer',
            'naturalidade_id'   => 'integer',
            'telefone1'         => 'required|max:45',
            'telefone2'         => 'max:45',
            'perfil_id'         => 'integer',
            'filial_id'         => 'integer'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function rules()
{

    $rules = [
        'nome' => 'required|max:100|min:2',
        'sobrenome' => 'required|max:100|min:2',
        'data_nascimento' => 'required|date',
        'rua' => 'required|max:300|min:2',
        'bairro' => 'required|max:300|min:2',
        'cidade_id' => 'integer',
        'semestre_id' => 'integer',
        'periodo_letivo_id' => 'integer',
        'email' => 'required|max:200|email|unique:usuario',
        'status' => 'required|integer',
        'profissao_id' => 'integer',
        'sexo_id' => 'integer',
        'naturalidade_id' => 'integer',
        'telefone1' => 'required|max:45',
        'telefone2' => 'max:45',
        'perfil_id' => 'integer',
        'filial_id' => 'integer'
    ];
    if (request()->id) {
        $rules['cpf'] = 'string';
        $rules['rg'] = 'string';
    } else {
        $rules['cpf'] = 'required|unique:usuario';
        $rules['rg'] = 'required|unique:usuario';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Tente fazer algo assim, ou criar um Request só pra atualização

Comment: Não entendo, achava que Ctrl+C Ctrl+V fosse mais simples do que por uma imagem...

Comment: Rafael, muito obrigado.. resolvido.

Comment: @Rafael Afonso, por favor, evite postar `imagens` de código nos seus posts - perguntas e/ou respostas. Para entender sobre os verdadeiros motivos leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer pergunta(https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas).

Answer (score 0):

Para validar os campos unique no update:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule; 

$rules = [
    'cpf' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
];
```

Mais informações em:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique